# What does RACK_ENV do in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a Rails application already in production. The guy before set these environment variables:

```
...
export RACK_ENV=none                                                                                                                  
export RAILS_ENV=production
...
```

What does `RACK_ENV=none` do? I can't find documentation on it anywhere. Do I need to set it in the Rails application or can I just delete that export?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO it's useless.

To find the current environment a Rails app first looks for the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable, then for `RACK_ENV` environment variable, then it defaults to `'development'`.

Comment: Do you know if Rack does something different when RACK_ENV var is set?

Comment: Look in sources : 
https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/ab172af1b63f0d8e91ce579dd2907c43b96cf82a/lib/rack/server.rb#L157

Answer (score 3):

If you're using version 1.7 or later of the database_cleaner gem, and your CI server has `RACK_ENV` set to `production` like mine did, you'll need to set `RACK_ENV` to `none` (or anything other than `production`) to appease database_cleaner's safeguard that your tests aren't running in production. (Or you could disable the safeguard altogether, but that seems less safe.)

Looking at current rack source, it appears that the only value of RACK_ENV that is meaningful to rack is `development`, which causes rack to default the host to `localhost` instead of to `0.0.0.0`. So it's foolish to set RACK_ENV to `production` in the first place, or to check that it's been set to that, but that foolishness has taken root all over.

Comment: Thank you Dave, you help me to solve my problem. I almost give up. So, I host my RoR app in Ubuntu docker with CaptainDuckDuck. So, to fix my problem, I just need to remove the `RACK_ENV production` in captain-definition file.